# Андроид приложение с двумя активити как точки входа

Tags: java, android, activity, android-manifest

Приложение содержит две `activity` как точки входа, как описано в манифесте.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.screen.main.MainActivity"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_tracker_launcher" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ui.screen.main.MapEnterActivity"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_watcher_launcher" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name_watcher" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Как результат - есть две иконки на рабочем столе устройства. По задумке по нажатию на каждую из иконок должна запускаться соответствующая активити.

Проблема сейчас состоит в том, что если пользователь нажимает "назад" (то есть приложение не убито) и потом хочет запустить другую иконку с другой активностью, то при запуске видит ту же самую активити.
Если же приложение принудительно убито пользователем - тогда все получается.
Само собой так быть не должно.

Как реализовать чтобы каждая иконка запускала свою активити независимо от вышеописанных факторов?

Спасибо за любые варианты.

Answer (score 4):

Описываемая вами функциональность достигается с помощью `shortcut`, вам надо в `res/xml/shortcuts.xml` прописать ссылки типа:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<! первая активити -->
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="tracker_launcher"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tracker_laucnher"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/tracker_launcher_short_label"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/tracker_laucnher_long_label"
    <intent
      android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
      android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
      android:targetClass=".ui.screen.main.MainActivity" />
  </shortcut>
<! вторая активити -->
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="watcher_launcher"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_watcher_laucnher"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/watcher_launcher_short_label"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/watcher_laucnher_long_label"
    <intent
      android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
      android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
      android:targetClass=".ui.screen.main.MapEnterActivity" />
  </shortcut>

</shortcuts>
```

Далее к ним создать т.н. Pinned Shortcut (то есть иконки-ссылки в лончере).

[Мануалы здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#java)

Answer (score 2):

Ответили на англоязычном стеке, копирую оттуда.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64177291/4974229

Нужно добавить параметр `android:taskAffinity` для каждой `activity`:

```
 <activity
    android:taskAffinity="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:name=".ui.screen.main.MainActivity"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_tracker_launcher" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:taskAffinity="com.example.MapEnterActivity"
    android:name=".ui.screen.main.MapEnterActivity"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_watcher_launcher" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name_watcher" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```